# get directory files on item click

Tags: android, listview

Hello First i am getting all files which are present in phone memory including directories and files , now i want that when i click on directory then all directory files should be added in list view here is my code

```
String dir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
    File f= new File(dir);
    File file[]=f.listFiles();
      for(int i=0; i<file.length; i++){


          System.out.println(file[i].getName());
            arrayList.add(file[i].getName());
          lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


    if (file[i].isDirectory()) {

        for (i = 0; i < file[i].length(); i++) {

            System.out.println(file[i].getName());
            arrayList.add(file[i].getName());
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the files from directory to add them to list view 
You should do something like that in your on click

```
    if (file[i].isDirectory()) {

File[] subfiles=file[i].listFiles();
            for (i = 0; i < subfiles.length(); i++) {

                System.out.println(subfiles[i].getName());
                arrayList.add(subfiles[i].getName());
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much adeel its working ,my problem is solved :)

Comment: Pleasure is all mine. ap ka msla solve hua mjy points mil gy ;D

Comment: what if i want  go another directory ?from one directory to another directory?

Comment: directory of file both are recieved in File object , u can check either the file object is directory or not using  if(file.isDirecotry()){
// here get the list of files from that directory as follow
File []f=file.litsFile();


}